# Запись матрицы в excel

Tags: java, excel

Допустим есть матрица, хочу ее записать в excel с помощью java.
Не подскажите подобную реализацию, с примером?

Answer (score 5):

Есть такая библиотека - [apache poi](http://poi.apache.org/)

Вот пример ее использования для формирования xls файла

```
void printMatrixToXls(double[][] matrix, String filename) {

    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("matrix");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
        double[] rowData = matrix[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < rowData.length; j++) {        
            row.createCell(j).setCellValue(rowData[j]);
        }
    }

    FileOutputStream out = null;    
try {
    out = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename));
    workbook.write(out);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();    
} finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
}}
```

Comment: так то это понятно,а если у меня уже сформированная матрица?куда её пихать? ну допустим я там создал матрицу размером 100 на 100 заполнил как то все она у меня есть.как ее указать в эти { }?Извините если как то глупо спрашиваю.

Comment: double[][] такой формат

Answer (score 0):

В "Spring in action" есть тема про работу с таблицами Excel.